# How can an EU citizen (Poland) obtain an Australian tourist visa from Saint Petersburg, Russia?

Tags: visas, australia, russia, polish-citizens, saint-petersburg

How can an EU citizen (Poland) obtain an Australian tourist visa while in Saint Petersburg, Russia?

Is it possible to do without returning to Poland?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visa applications for Australia can be done completely online! (For Australia)

So firstly, to confirm, yes [Polish citizens do need a visa for Australia](http://www.evisaasia.com/australia-tourist-visa-requirements-for-polish-citizens).

Then, apply for it online.  There are [sites explaining the whole process](http://www.evisaasia.com/australia-visa).

> Travelers are not required to visit the Australian embassy nor send in
>   their passports. Once online visa applications are approved,
>   applicants will receive their visa by email, which is recognized by
>   all airlines traveling inbound to Australia and provided that all your
>   travel documents are in order, you should have no trouble boarding
>   your flight to Australia.

Answer (score 6):

Australia now does electronic Visas for most tourist Visas, so you will likely be able to apply over the Internet at http://www.immi.gov.au/.

There is no need to have a physical stamp in your passport, and no need send your passport anywhere.